# How to get max value of a item in dynamoDB using node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to get max value from **id** item. I am using ScanIndexForward:false which returns desc order of **id** values which is not working as expected now its giving the same insertion order from the table.

Please see my code below and please suggest if any changes required.

```
var params1 = {
    TableName: "Test",
    Limit:3,
    ProjectionExpression: 'id',
    ScanIndexForward:false,
    };
docClient.scan(params1, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded."+JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You are performing a [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html), which does not have a parameter called `ScanIndexForward`. The [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation does have a parameter called `ScanIndexForward`.

The only way you can order results in a DynamoDB query is by the sort key attribute - results are ordered by default. If you want to order by any other attribute, or order scan results, you have to do it in your client application.